# lsp-pyright defer init until a .py file is open

Tags: python, use-package, start-up, lsp-mode

Hey guys i'm improving my startup, Emacs version 28.2.

I did a benchmark on init and I noticed that the thing that takes most of the time is lsp-pyright. That initializes lsp-mode.

But I don't understand why this module is loaded at startup. This happens with this mode alone

Here is my config

```
(use-package lsp-mode
  :hook ((python-mode      ;
          js-mode          ;
          js-jsx-mode      ;
          typescript-mode  ;
          web-mode         ;
          markdown-mode
          haskell-mode     ;
          zig-mode         ;
          elm-mode         ;
          odin-mode        ;
          rust-mode        ;
          ) . lsp-deferred)
  :commands lsp
  :config
  (setq lsp-auto-guess-root t)
  (setq lsp-log-io nil)
  (setq lsp-restart 'auto-restart)
  (setq read-process-output-max (* 1024 1024))
  (setq lsp-idle-delay 0.5))

(use-package lsp-ui
  :commands lsp-ui-mode
  :config
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-enable nil)
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-header t)
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-include-signature t)
  (setq lsp-ui-doc-border (face-foreground 'default))
  (setq lsp-ui-sideline-show-code-actions t)
  (setq lsp-ui-sideline-delay 0.05))

;; pyright
(use-package lsp-pyright
  :hook (python-mode . (lambda ()
                         (require 'lsp-pyright)
                         (lsp-deferred))))
```

Comment: Please don't use images unless an image is *required* to show the problem. For text like your config above, just paste it into the question in between triple backticks (a backtick is the character in the upper left corner of a US keyboard, although YMMV).

Comment: @NickD Oh I didn't know!. Fixed!

Comment: Add ```:defer 1``` before ```:hook``` in your ```lsp-mode``` configuration; check also the buffer ```lsp-log``` - usually ```lsp-pyright``` scraps the computer for all ```.py``` files and add watchers to them (I have ~11k of such watchers) - there are some indications what is not right.